# Override vs Overwrite

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Overriding… overwriting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738315/c-overriding-overwriting)

What's the difference between `override` and `overwrite`? I've heard them used interchangeably but I suspect that's incorrect.

Comment: Do you mean "override vs. **overload**"?

Comment: overwrite is not a common C++ term.

Comment: @VaughnCato, well, you work with files in c++ as well ;-)

Comment: @Dave: I can't think of a situation in C++ where "overwrite" is used in a technical sense (other than the standard English sense of overwriting some data).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson agreed, dupe, please close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`override` is a C++11 keyword used to override base virtual method:

```
class A
{
    virtual f(int) {}
};

class B
{
    virtual f(int) override {} // override A::f(int)
};
```

This lets you make sure that `A::F(int)` gets overriden, meaning you are not creating new virtual function.
Of course this code won't compile if the function signature was different.

overwrite is not C++ keyword and it basically means to overwrite some file or text with new one.

The keyword `override` has been introduced because some times a programmer doesn't know whether he is overriding or whether he is creating a new virtual method with a different signature.
Using that keyword you either get an error or override virtual method.

Comment: Would +1 if not for the number of typos in the answer...

Answer (score 3):

You can only overwrite what's been written and where it's been written, while you can override things elsewhere (for instance you can override members of base class in derived classes).